# NDSolve break condition

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm solving a differential equation numerically by

```
NDSolve[{p'[r] == -function[r,p[r]], p[0] == pcenter}, p,{r, 0, rmax}]
```

with function>0. At some r, p[r] becomes negative. I want NDSolve to stop as soon as this happens and save the value of r. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: [WhenEvent](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) is what you want

Comment: exactly. thank you!

Comment: @acl I posted an answer using what I learned from your comment. Thanks! By the way, I'm involving you in [an experiment](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/answered-but-unanswered-questions-a-self-serving-proposal) without your permission (sorry!)

Comment: @Ian excellent, up voted. Happy to serve as a guinea pig.

Comment: @lan I read through your experiment. I feel reluctant to formally accept your answer though because I never actually tested the code

Comment: DanielR I wonder if I could press you to actually test the code and see if it does satisfy your question, in which case it may well deserve acceptance. If at all possible, this would close the circle on @Ian's laudable experiment... Thank you!

Comment: @MarcoB You are too kind. I do consider getting more answers posted, even if not accepted, a huge improvement.

Comment: Well it works ;) What I mean is that in the general case, once the question is answered (even in form of a comment), the asking person in most cases won't feel like reproducing the error or whatever just to mark an answer as such. And the whole point of this is to get a formally unanswered question marked green, isn't it.

EDIT: Well, I guess a worked out solution, even if not formally answered, is still better than 'just' a comment for anyone else having the same question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `WhenEvent[event, action]` can be included in the list `eqn` used in `NDSolve[eqn,__]`. For example:

```
eqn = {
  p'[r] == -p[r] - 1,
  p[0] == 1,
  WhenEvent[p[r] == 0, rMax = r; "StopIntegration"]
};
sol = NDSolve[eqn, p, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
Plot[p[r] /. sol, {r, 0, rMax}]
```

Comment: FYI: The last `r` is in fact the endpoint of the domain of the solution.  The domain may be obtained with `p["Domain"] /. sol`. (Of course, it can be convenient to save it in a variable `rMax` as you did, too.)